# Finding the number of ways to pick ${n}$ marbles from a jar

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:**

А jar contains 8 blue marbles, 6 green marbles, and 4 red marbles. Five marbles are selected at random, all at once. In how many ways can:

A.) two red and three blue marbles be obtained?

B.) two green and two blue marbles be obtained?

C.) two red marbles be obtained?

D.) two or more green marbles be obtained?

---

**Work:**

A.) $4\cdot3\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{2}$ = $40,320$

B.) $6\cdot5\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{2}$ = $100,800$

C.) $4\cdot3\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{2}$ = $158,400$

D.) ($6\cdot5\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{2}$) + ($6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot12\cdot11 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{3}$) + ($6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot12 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{4}$) + ($6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2 $ $\cdot$ $_{5}C_{5}$) = $576,720$

**Is all of work correct?**

Comment: How would you have answered $B$ if you had been asked to pick 3 blue balls instead of 2?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt y Yes I see made a mistake in B.

Comment: It looks as if none are correct. For example, the first should be $\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{3}$.

Comment: When you say 'two red marbles obtained', do you mean exactly or at least 2?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt I assume it's at least 2 and the rest can be green or blue. Sorry if the question seems to poorly formatted but this is how the question is framed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you explain what you think I did wrong and why is the answer is $4\choose2$$8\choose3$? Maybe I overcount or something?

Comment: You appear to be trying to take into account the order of choosing. The problem is explicit about "all at once.": I have written answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume (as we are expected to) that the marbles are distinguishable.

A.) There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the reds. For each of these ways, there are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to choose the blues, for a total of $\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{3}$.

B.) We interpret the question as asking for *exactly* $2$ green and exactly $2$ blue, so $1$ red. The same reasoning as above gives $\binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{4}{1}$.

C.) The $2$ red can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Now we must choose $3$ non-red from the $14$ non-red.

D.) It's your turn.

Comment: So for D it would ($6\choose2$$12\choose3$) + ($6\choose3$$12\choose2$) + ($6\choose4$$12\choose1$) + ($6\choose5$?

Comment: Yes. Or else subtract $0$ green, $1$ green from the total possible number of choices. That does not make things significantly easier here, but the strategy might make a big difference in other problems.

Comment: You are welcome.